# How to create a csv output with freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

The input to my freemarker template is records: `List<List<String>> records = new ArrayList();`
each list inside records is a row from a database;
I need to create a csv;
How I can write values of a row in a separate line to create a csv.

Here is my freemarker template:
for now it write any value in a different line.

```````````
   <#list records>
    <#items as record>
        <#list record>
        <#items as value>
           ${value},
        </#items>
        </#list>
    </#items>
    </#list>

``````````
```````````

Answer (score 0):

In simple cases `#items` is not needed, so I give the example without that (but same approach works with `#items` as well).

```
<#list record as value>${value}<#sep>,</#list>
```

That is, `#list` (and `#items`) just repeatedly prints the content nested between its start tag and end tag (except, it ignores the line-break directly after the start tag). So if you don't have a line-break at the end of the nested content, then it doesn't print a line-break.

As of `#sep`, I added that because you don't want comma after the last value of the record.